# jQuery Ui dialog is not showing

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to use jQuery Ui dialog. Here is my code

```
<body>

    <div id="myDialog" title="This is the title!">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean sollicitudin. Sed
        interdum pulvinar justo. Nam iaculis volutpat ligula. Integer vitae felis quis diam
        laoreet ullamcorper. Etiam tincidunt est vitae est.            
    </div> <!--end of id="myDialog" -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquey.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($){
            $("#myDialog").dialog();
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>
```

But i am getting error

```
uiDialogTitlebar.find("*").add(uiDialogTitlebar).disableSelection is not a function
```

Why this error is coming and how can i fix it? I am using FireFox 11.0

Thanks

Comment: You have not posted all of your code... please post whatever code is producing the error.  I just pasted your code to jsfiddle and it "works" http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/xCZCf/

Comment: This is the full code. Actually i used this code from the book. I have also that book source codes. When i copy paste the code from that book source code to my IDE, then it started working. I don't know why it was not working before, because both the codes are same. No spelling mistake. I don't know why it was not working :(

Answer (score 0):

jquery 1.7 not work well with jquery ui.
When you click to object with options jquery ui - his load jquery 1.7 second time, and in this issue.
loock at firebug or chrome network(load files in site)

Comment: HHmm thanks you mean i need to use jQuery version below 1.7? what do you mean by `When you click to object with options jquery ui - his load jquery 1.7 second time`. Which object clicking you are talking about? Thanks